# devpi :: AttributeError: 'FileUpload' object has no attribute 'value' :: when uploading

Tags: python, pypi, devpi

Out of the sudden, package uploads fail to devpi with the error:

```
AttributeError: 'FileUpload' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a regression or API change or whatever it is in `bottle` you should never care about, because `devpi` should care about it itself by pinning the correct versions of all libraries it depends on.

Anyway, you can circumvent the trouble by installing `bottle==0.11.6` before installing devpi.

```
$ pip install bottle==0.11.6
$ pip install devpi
```

Comment: This is a bug in bottle 0.12.11 caused by a security fix that was released recently. Fixed in bottle-0.12.12 and master. The bugfix release will be available any minute now.